# Change Path of Python Interpreter/Compiler

Tags: python, pip, path

I have a Folder (python311) where I have all of the Python Components stored ("Lib", "Scripts", "python.exe" ...) which is on this Path: D:\python311.
Now I want to move this Folder (python311) into another Folder (Code) -> Path: D:\Code\python311.
Using VS Code it lets me choose the Interpreter which is fine, but when I want to intsll new modules with pip, it does not work. It tries to create an process between the Interpreter of the old Path (D:\python311\python.exe), which is no longer existent, and the new Path where pip is stored (D:\Code\python311\Scripts\pip.exe).

Solutions that I can think of would be for example reinstalling Python. I don't know if it can be solved through environment variables but it won't work because I store the Python Components on an external Drive.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using environment variables even if it is on an external drive.

You will need to remove the old entry in the `PATH` variable and add the new entry (the new python path) or edit the old entry to include the new path.

Comment: Is there a way to check it?
There are two sections, the system-variables and the user-variables, in both of them there is a "Path" variable but their entries refer to a very different location.

Comment: You can add it to the system variables.

Comment: I think I do not get it.
I added D:\python311\python.exe to the entry of "Path" under the system-variables.
Is this correct? It still does not work this way.

Comment: What do you get exactly when you execute the pip command?

Comment: ```Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"D:\python311\python.exe"  "D:\Code\python311\scripts\pip.exe" ': The system can not find the stated file```

Answer (score 0):

Change path in environment variables -> Path

Furthermore, I have all my Pythons installed in same location:

```
PS C:\Python> ls

    Directory: C:\Python

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----           22.8.2022    11.23                p105_32
d----           15.8.2022    17.12                p105_64
```

When I want to use different versions I create a new virtual environment [Virtualenvwrapper](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/configuring-python-environment-with-virtualenvwrapper-8745c2895745).

```
mkvirtualenv envname -p C:/Python/p105_32
workon envname
```

Comment: I cannot find the enviroment variable. Is there a way to check it?
There are two sections, the system-variables and the user-variables, in both of them there is a "Path" variable but their entries refer to a very different location.